# How to get back my money

Tags: mining, scam, airdrop

I put my money in humble to mining ETH .. i apply for link and linked with my wallet to start mining
https://ljuzwm.top/#/
Everything was ok once i apply to reward they deduct the balance and ask me for additional 5270 ! Otherwise they will reserve my money for 180 days but i dont believe them ! I tried to call them to customer services and they told me this is the rules ! Please help me guys

Answer (score 1):

That's a wallet drainer. sorry your money is gone mate

Comment: Anyone can help guys